# Track last ajax call of website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know its a bit stupid question which is a bit meaningless but still I wanted to know is there any way to track last ajax call on page.

Actually the issue is I developed an application which works with ajax and many ajax calls happening with different different actions but if no ajax request call for 10 mins. it will expire session but I don't want it on just ajax call.

What I Want

if no activity happens in 10 mins. I don't wanna do anything but if even any click or keyboard activity happens then it will make 1 more ajax in after 10 mins. of click so session will not expire.

But that's not the issue to write script for it but the issue is I've lots of page and lots of different ajax call's so I just want to track last ajax call time on page.

I don't know if there's any possible way or not for it so I didn't write any code yet if any its possible then I'll start writing script otherwise I'll find another way but I appreciate if someone suggest me a way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ajaxsetup` and increment a variable in `ajaxsetup`. Because `ajaxsetup` call in every `ajax` call

see the documentation of ajaxsetup http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/

Comment: can you provide me any documentation link for it ?

Comment: thanks from this page I found ajaxComplete and it works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your session not to expire, then increase its duration :

Adding this to your script will set php sessions lifetime to a month :

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 2678400);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 2678400);
```

**EDIT** for comment below :

To track last call add this at the beginning of your application entry point :

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
   $_SESSION['last_ajax_call'] = time();
}
```

Comment: I don't want to increase its time if no activity found I want to track last ajax call so I will track I've to expand session or not

Comment: I can't find any key "HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH" for $_SERVER in php.net

Comment: try : `var_dump($_SERVER);` and make an ajax request to it.

Answer (score 0):

declare one variable and set 0 at the end of ajax request and change the value of variable as per time

i think this will help you

Comment: yes I know that but the issue is I've lots of ajax function in more than 40 pages I can't do manually in all